# Quarkus verifying JWTs from multiple sources

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus, jwk, smallrye

Is there a way to allow JWTs from multiple sources?

I have a REST API that I only allow access to via Bearer Tokens authentication, and I really only need to verify these tokens, so I don't really need all the additions that OIDC brings.

Let's say I have Keycloak set up as an Identity Provider. I would configure quarkous-oidc accordingly. But now I also want to allow JWTs that I create in another service, for service to service communication. This is not an identity provider, but i rather just use smallrye-jwt to create some "internal" tokens.

So it actually seems that I would rather use quarkus-smallrye-jwt, but I can't configure it for multiple tenants.

I think consolidating the keys in a JWKS and providing that to quarkus-smallrye-jwt would eventually work. But maybe there is a more elegant solution that I didn't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With microprofile-jwt(smallrye-jwt) you have an option to use [JWKS(Json Web Key Set)](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-jwt-auth/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/configuration.asciidoc#json-web-key-set-jwks) as your `mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location` property. That allows you to trust tokens issued by multiple issuers.
However, you will not be able to, for example, validate multiple values in `issuer` field of the jwt token as it only supports single value, or define different config per issuer.

You can create the JWKS manually, combining the key info from your auth providers and embedding/mounting it in your app, or you can implement some endpoint that produces it dynamically(e.g. it would periodically call the 2 Keycloaks JWKS urls and combine the output producing new JWKS)

If you need more control over the validation, then you'll need to create your own implementation and integrate it with MP JWT/Quarkus. One option could be to provide a custom `JWTCallerPrincipalFactory` to smallrye-jwt - see [docs about custom factories](https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-jwt/configuration.html#_custom_factories). There you could read any custom config (e.g. `my.app.jwt.issuers=trustedIssuer1,trustedIssuer2` and handle the validation yourself, maybe reusing classes already provided by smallrye (`JWTAuthContextInfo`, `JWTParser`...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the meantime, I have actually tried both ways.

The first with the combined JWKS actually doesn't work because of the issuer verification.

But I have had success with a custom implementation of the JWTCallerPrincipalFactory. That way I use the default parser, with the configuration grabbed from the default configuration.

I then create another JWTAuthContextInfo from my custom config which I use with my custom parser, that verifies my "internal" JWTs.

Comment: Does the property also allow PEM files containing multiple certificates?